# Why is the console hanging randomly?

Tags: server, virtualbox, console

Ubuntu 10.10 Server x64 installed as Virtual Box VM.

Fresh install plus postgresql and tomcat6 installed via aptitude. Rebooted the server and now when I run some command the console hangs. For instance, I run "sudo shutdown now" and then nothing happens but I am not returned to the prompt. I hit CTRL+C and nothing happens except ^C appears on the following line. I can type whatever and it will show up inline.

I switch to tty2 and try to login and I only get as far as [username][enter] and that console hangs.

One other thing - after "sudo reboot" the console appears to hang (just like above) when shutting down tomcat6.

Any idea what's going on or what I should check?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you modified ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc ?

Comment: No, I haven't manually modified any config files. Just the two installs I mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: during your install did you specify partitions to be mounted that are no longer present?

Comment: No I didn't, I used auto/guided mode. I've just removed the web app that was deployed to tomcat6 and performances seems to be back to normal. So that narrows it down!

Comment: If that is the solution you might want to post it as an answer to your won question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be the DHIS2 WAR I had deployed to the tomcat6 installation. Stopping tomcat6 and removing the WAR and the directory and then rebooting has fixed the problem. I haven't diagnosed farther than that yet.